# Embed dynamic php snippets with parameters in a blogpost

Tags: php, functions, parameter

I have a setup where I embed some entities in my blogposts (products essentially) and then I have written a script and added to `functions.php` where I can all an API to get some metadata about each product.

I've successfully used plugins to insert PHP snippets but it has the same caveat as the other solutions I've found: they only allow for the same snippet to be run. What I need to figure out how to call my function with a different parameter each time and not just a once-and-for-all embed of the same call.

```
getMetadata(link1) 

getMetadata(link2)
```

Could someone guide me towards a solution or the outlines of one?

Comment: questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here, so you can't ask for help with xyz php here, but, what you're trying to do is not normally done with a plugin like that. The official methods for doing this are shortcodes, widgets, and blocks, with PHP placed in PHP files, not the database/WP Admin. E.g. a shortcode might look like this: `[myshortcode link="...."]`. Storing and executing HPP code directly in the database in post content is very dangerous and a massive security risk

Comment: hi Tom. I understand that. The XYZ was just to show that what's usually considered the solution for this and that it won't work. Can you elaborate on the shortcode approach in this case? I'll also try to google ofc

Comment: I was just listing examples, there are already lots of good questions about how to build shortcodes or blocks on the site that are better than anything i could fit in a comment. PHP plugins aren't the normal approach, they're usually suggested by hosting company support because it saves teaching users FTP/etc when they may be non-technical and just want to copy paste something they found. Fundamentally you're asking "How do I embed PHP in post content"

Comment: Makes sense. For future reference: I figured out how to achieve what I wanted using `add_shortcode`